# How do I change the tab group colors in IE8?

Tags: colors, internet-explorer-8, browser-tabs

Is there a way to change the tab group colors in IE8?

Comment: From my brief search, it doesn't look like it. You might try poking through the registry to see if anything relevant is there.

Answer (score 2):

I made a bunch of them and tried various ways of changing the colors but I don't think it can be done (from the front end).

Answer (score 0):

In [this article about IE8 tab grouping](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/09/30/ie8-tab-grouping.aspx) it seems you can turn off tab grouping altogether under Tab Options. No option to change the colors or just turn these colors off (second one seems obvious: how would the groups make any sense when you can't see them), but turning off the tab grouping feature entirely might remove the colors?

Answer (score 0):

2 possible solution:

1. Participate in Microsoft Customer Experience Improvement Program and provide this feedback
2. Recommend firefox or google chrome to have this feature plus colour choices available then microsot IE may like to follow suit